# Is it possible to track background location in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Is there good libraries to track location in the background react-native?
I see this one so far https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation
But it seems unsupported

Answer (score 1):

Check this npm package [react-native-background-geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-geolocation)

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: ahh thank you, but that is a paid for service